# Gitblit: how to clone develop branch with change the cloneBranch in gitblit-1.8.0\data\groovy\localclone.groovy

Tags: git, gitblit

I changed the cloneBranch to `refs/heads/develop` or to `develop`,but it always cloning the master branch. So,how to clone develop branch ?

not checkout branch,and [this is the link of gitblit](http://gitblit.com/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to checkout to other branch from master branch to clone it

Reference

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/19

Comment: There are two branches:develop and master,also has pushed to remote repository,so,I don't understand how to solve it